# Ruby Spread sheet OLE issue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ole

I upgrade application from Rails 2 to Rails 3 using ruby 1.9.3.Everything works fine in Rails 2 with ruby 1.8.7.I have gem "spreadsheet" in gem file . But while running rails server, it throws error like this "rake aborted!
undefined method `new0' for Ole::Types::FileTime:Class"

Answer (score 3):

Try with

```
bundle update ruby-ole
```